# Set presence to true for RSpec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'd like to set the presence of something to "true" for a particular instance that I'm testing. It currently does not exist, so its presence == false.

Here's the code I have so far. Hope someone can help.

in invitations_controller:

```
def join_request
  invitation_options = {recipient_id: current_user.id, project_id: @project.id, recipient_email: current_user.email}

  if ProjectInvitation.where(invitation_options).present?
    flash[:notice] = "You already sent a request to join this project."
    redirect_to :back
    return
  end
```

in invitations_controller_spec:

```
describe "Send Join Request" do
  before do
    @invitation_options = {:recipient_id => @user.id, :project_id => @project.id, :recipient_email => 'address@gmail.com'}
    ProjectInvitation.where(@invitation_options).present? == true # This is what I'm stuck on. Pretty sure this doesn't work.
  end
  context "if you already sent a request" do
    it "should tell you that you already sent a request" do
      response.should have_text("You already sent a request to join this project.")
    end
    it "should redirect you to the previous page" do
      response.should redirect_to(:back)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily stub 'where' method, but it will stub all you queries for this model. Example:

```
Profile.stub(:where) { "555" }
Profile.where(:id => 5) #will return 555
Profile.where(:name => 'Phil') #will return 555
```

But the best way is to use FactoryGirl to generate ProjectInvitation

Answer (score 0):

consider extracting this query (`ProjectInvitation.where(invitation_options).present?`) to a class method in `ProjectInvitation` and then stub it in your test

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, does that mean I still have to create all of these values? Is there no way to just set the presence of that entry to "true" for this particular instance?

Answer (score 0):

> stub current_user method. create a project with factory and then
>   simply create ProjectInvitation with attributes {recipient_id:
>   current_user.id, project_id: @project.id, recipient_email:
>   current_user.email} in your spec.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into using FactoryGirl for this.